# bootstrap.typeahead and knockout bindings

Tags: knockout.js, bootstrap-typeahead, knockout-validation

I have the following code that does the typeahead and works fine unless someone uses tab key to fill out the textfield. The value remains "" / empty in knockout bindings if selected via tab key and validation fails.

```
$('.typeahead').each(function(){
    var typeaheadItem = localStorage.getItem($(this).attr('name'));

    if(typeaheadItem != null){
        var values = typeaheadItem.split(',');      

        $(this).typeahead({                                   
            local: values
        })
    }           
});
```

i did google and found loads of various solutions but can't figure them out. i modified the following lines

```
        $(this).typeahead({                                   
            local: values
        }).on('typeahead:selected', function (el, item) {
            updateValues(item.value);
        }).on('typeahead:autocompleted', function (el, item) {
            updateValues(item.value);
        });
```

and added a function updateValues. what should i put in the updateValues for it to work.

```
var updateValues = function (val) {

};
```

Comment: Use a binding handler, not a jQuery selector, to manipulate DOM items. Fortunately, one is already written for typeahead:
http://billpull.com/knockout-bootstrap/#typeahead

Comment: Thanks Roy, I'll answer this question when i figure out the link you provided.